# Can Gerunds be used to show result or purpose?

Tags: gerunds

I was studying when I saw this and got curious to know if gerunds can be used to show results or purpose in this way ->
*"Packages are the same as a directory containing other sub-packages and modules in a structured way, **making** the sub-packages and modules easy to access."*

Comment: That's not actually the gerund, because it's being used as an **adverb** (the phrase which begins with *making...* modifies the adjective *same*) instead of a **noun**. Instead, it is the present participle, which looks exactly the same as the gerund but is a modifier instead of a substantive. So, your original sentence is not an example of the gerund showing "result or purpose." That doesn't mean it's not possible though - you might say something like "Packages are the same... which has *the result of making* the sub-packages..." There, the gerund (obj. prep.) *does* express result.

Comment: It trad grammar, the "making" in your example is not a gerund but a present participle. However, the _making_ clause as a whole does have a resultative meaning.

Comment: @BillJ I believe you have just answered OP's question, and more concisely than I could have :)  Unfortunately I'm out of comment upvotes for the day...

Comment: Putting aside the question of what to call it, since you've just provided an example of an -ing form expressing purpose or result, I'd say it's obvious that they can be used in this way. If you have a reason to doubt this, please provide it and we can judge if it's valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sentence 'making' is a present participle and the first word in a participial phrase. It is not a gerund. To be a gerund, 'making' would have to function as the subject and be followed a verb (action/state). No verb follows in that dependent clause. Regardless of any gerund vs. particple debate, the sentence works as you've written it.

Nevertheless, if it helps to determine whether 'making' is a gerund or present partciple in your sentence, test by substituting 'and' for the comma after 'way': "... in a structured way and make the sub-packages...". Q: WHAT makes? A: Packages. Packages is the subject of the main clause.

The dependent clause is a participial phrase that gives us additional information about the main clause. It is dependent on the subject of the main clause. Stated in the context of the meaning of the sentence, the result, 'making', is dependent on the cause, 'Packages', the subject of the main clause.

Comment: I agree, though I wouldn't call it a 'dependent clause'. Result adjuncts are characteristically prosodically detached (as in the OP's example), with the status of supplements, and thus are not dependents.